# Commit failed with unknown error; commiting changes to VS using TFVC plugin

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, exception, tfs, tfvc

I'm using TFVC plugin with my Android Studio and I'm trying to commit my changes but it's returning the following error:

[image]

I checked my TF executable path and it's returning a valid TF executable found.

I'm able to update directory using TFVC but I'm not able to commit changes.

**EDIT:**
I'm able to update my local repo from the remote repo. Also, I was able to create a new branch, but I'm not able to checkin any code.

I even tried to completely delete my workspace and project locally, then I re-cloned the project from remote repo.

Still not working.

**EDIT2:**

I tried signing out and signing in from VS team services by going to Android Studio--> VCS--> Checkout from version control--> Team Services TFVC.

I was able to sign back, but I got prompted with an Plugin Error saying:
*10:20 AM   Plugin Error: Visual Studio Team Services threw an uncaught TeamServicesException. Disable Plugin*

Clicked on it for more details, and I got the following Dialog:

[image]

***The error is the following:***

getAuthenticationInfoAsync failed: KEY_VSO_AUTH_FAILED
com.microsoft.alm.plugin.exceptions.TeamServicesException: KEY_VSO_AUTH_FAILED
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.authentication.facades.VsoAuthInfoProvider.getAuthenticationInfoAsync(VsoAuthInfoProvider.java:98)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.authentication.VsoAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync(VsoAuthenticationProvider.java:69)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.common.LookupHelper.authenticateAndLoadVsoContexts(LookupHelper.java:158)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.checkout.VsoCheckoutPageModel.loadRepositories(VsoCheckoutPageModel.java:79)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.checkout.CheckoutPageController.actionPerformed(CheckoutPageController.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.controls.Hyperlink.notifyActionListeners(Hyperlink.java:91)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.controls.Hyperlink.access$000(Hyperlink.java:25)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.controls.Hyperlink$1.linkSelected(Hyperlink.java:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:156)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:350)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:327)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1660)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.common.BaseDialogImpl.showModalDialog(BaseDialogImpl.java:194)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.common.ui.checkout.CheckoutController.showModalDialog(CheckoutController.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea.tfvc.extensions.TfvcCheckoutProvider.doCheckout(TfvcCheckoutProvider.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.checkout.CheckoutAction.actionPerformed(CheckoutAction.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Not sure if that is related, but I wanted to add it in there.

Comment: Does this issue occur on other machines? Also check if other users have the same issue.

Comment: I'm the only one using Android Studio with TFVC plugin. The rest are using VS2017 for check-ins, branching, and updates.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the issue occurs with different user accounts, also check on other client machines.

Besides, make sure you have set the correct permission for the user account on TFS, you need the **Check in** permission at least.

---

**UPDATE:**

That's just a sample for you. Not the `Contributors` group, just check the permission of the user account which you used. Besides, according to the log you post, seems it's an issue with the Authentication of the plugin.

Refer to jchharris's reply in this similar thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-intellij/issues/107  , Just try to change the plugin to use Device Flow for the Authentication Method.

[image]

Comment: My administrator just checked Contributors--> the access control summary, and it's showing as "allow" under check in. Also, other accounts are using Visual Studio for check-in and updates. I'm the only one using Android Studio/TFVC plugin.

Comment: @RedM That's just a sample for you. Not the `Contributors` group, just check the permission of the user account which you used. Besides, according to the log you post, seems it's an issue with the Authentication of the plugin. See this similar thread : https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-intellij/issues/107

Comment: @RedM I suggest you uninstall the TFS plugin first (make sure clearly removed ), then re-install and configure it again to check if that works.

Comment: I tried uninstalling the plugin and installing it back but it did not work. Got the same "Commit failed with error" dialog box message.

Comment: @RedM Seems it's an issue with the plugin, please try to close the Android Studio and  clean the client caches , then start it again to check if that works. Also try to start the Android Studio  with another user (create a local user, then logon OS with that user, then start  Android Studio ).

Answer (score 0):

The plugin seems to access git through https therefore you might need to set the https proxy for git with the below command

```
git config --global http.proxy your-prox-server:port
```